# jQuery class selector and click handling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I do have couple divs, some of them are visible and some of them or not but each contains a

```
<a> tag with some_class
```

In the js script I do the following:

```
$('.some_class').click(someFunc)
```

And the someFunc is executed when I click on the link within div that was visible from the beginning but when I click on the link within div which was hidden (but is visible now) the someFunc is not executed. I do not have any idea why this could happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need event delegation:

```
$(document).on('click','.some_class',someFunc});
```

Comment: can you explain why to use event delegation?

Comment: Why wrap the call to `someFunc` in another function?

Comment: @xdumaine There is no reason for that.. both are same.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Actually, you're wrong that they're the same. The value of `this` is different in each method. See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VACAu/).

Comment: @xdumaine In the perspective of `this` it seems different and it should be. But I said that both are same in the way the code executed.

Comment: some_class is hidden when jQuery is run, you should attach a delegated event to the document, so it will run when there is a viewable some_classelement in the future

Answer (score 0):

If you want the event to be bound to them, then use `delegate()` method of jQuery.

Comment: who said like this to you.? your point is completely wrong.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy I am correct, please see the upvoted answer. It says the same thing in other words. You might want to take your downvote back.

Comment: ok i'll remove the dv.. but your answer seems wrong.. we can bind events to hidden elements since they are available in DOM while we attaching events to them..

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy that's when you use 'visibility:hidden'

Comment: `If you are using 'display:none' then page is treated as if they didn't exist, so the even't won't be bind to them. ` this part is completly wrong. You can bind events on elements which are hidden, only problem is you can't click on them since then are hidden you must show the element to trigger the event or trigger the event manually. http://jsfiddle.net/nGFx4/

Comment: @Anton http://jsfiddle.net/JLwK5/

Comment: @Anton I think I was wrong, thanks for correcting me.

Comment: The reason to use event delegation is for elements which are dynamically added to the DOM, but not because they become visible.